# Наследование атрибутов С++

Tags: c++, c++11, наследование

Могу ли я сделать так, чтобы при вызове метода honk у Car, атрибут brand брался с Car, а не с Vehicle ?

```
// Base class
class Vehicle {
  public: 
    string brand;
    void honk() {
      cout << brand;
    }
};

// Derived class
class Car: public Vehicle {
  public: 
    string brand = "Mustang";
};

int main() {
  Car myCar;
  myCar.honk(); /* "Mustang", а не пустая строка.*/
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Возвращайте строку через виртуальную функцию.

Comment: Типа [такого](https://ideone.com/DKDoub). Но лучше сразу `brand` сделать функцией.

Comment: Внтури `Car` две разных строки.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Все, что делает `honk`, выполнить в виртуальной функции_члене, а в `honk` просто вызвать эту функцию_член, то есть  изменить поведение `honk` в зависимости от разновидности транспортного средства:

```
class Vehicle {
    string brand{ "vehicle" };
public:
    virtual void  b() { cout << brand; }
    void honk() {
        b();
    }
};

class Car : public Vehicle {
    string brand{ "mustang" };
public:   
    void  b() { cout << brand; }
};
int main() {
    Car myCar;
    myCar.honk();
    return 0;
}
```

Но часто, как и в данном случаи, лучше не заводить еще один член в производном классе, а занести в базовом классе в защищенное или открытое поле, затем изменить значение в производном классе.

```
class Vehicle {
protected:
    string brand{ "vehicle" };
public:    
    void honk() {
        cout << brand;
    }
};

class Car : public Vehicle {    
public:   
    Car() { brand = "mustang"; }
};
```

Так можно избавиться от лишнего хранения в объектах лишнего поля и неявного указателя на таблицу виртуальных функций _ экономить и в памяти и выиграть в скорости

Comment: А надо ли вообще хранить в одном объекте две строки? Какой в этом смысл?

Comment: @Mikhailo, если они  содержат разного рода информации(например род транспортного средства и  технические данные автомобиля), то возможно и надо.

Comment: По-моему, одинаковое их имя и одинаковый вывод одинаковой функцией говорит не только об одинаковости семантики этих строк, но и о непонимании, что такое наследование, у ТС.

Answer (score 2):

А надо ли вообще хранить в одном объекте две строки? Какой в этом смысл?

Написать нормальные конструкторы и проще, и понятнее. И никаких лишних накладных расходов.

```
// Base class
class Vehicle {
public:
    Vehicle(const string& brand = ""):brand(brand){}
    string brand;
    void honk() {
        cout << brand;
    }
};

// Derived class
class Car: public Vehicle {
public:
    Car():Vehicle("Mustang"){};
};

int main() {
    Car myCar;
    myCar.honk(); /* "Mustang", а не пустая строка.*/
    return 0;
}
```